# Addressing varying field amounts on Report

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am in a service based industry in which we generate engagement letters for clients. The clents vary and could have between 1 to 13 services. One client could have 2 services, another could have 13 and so on and so forth. Same with the fees that we list. I have the data in a report (I've attached a picture below but am new and unsure if it will show) but my issue is that the report, although it will suppress blank fields, will not "roll up" (for lack of better term) between the spaces for all services.

EG:

Client address, etc at top of letter, then

You have requested the following services:
Service001
Service002 
Service003 
Service004 (to 13)

Our Fees will be as follows: 
Fee001
Fee002  (to 13)

The "Our fees will be as follows" is a label and will not move up if a client only has say 2 services. Is there a work around or am I better writing some vba to create like a memo field that lumps all the services into it so that 1 memo field can grow or shrink? Of course I'd probably have the same issue I am thinking.

I would appreciate some insight. I am at the beginning of this process and so changing my bones wouldn't be a big deal. Thank you so much for at least reading this :)

[image]

Comment: Multiple similar name fields with same kind of data indicates a non-normalized data structure. Should be a related dependent table where each service selected is a record, not a field. You should research database normalization.

Comment: I should have added more detail. Unfortunately, I have an older admin who refuses to use anything other than our client fees and services spreadsheet, so I have to work with the data imported from there. The services and fees can vary greatly and need to be edited on the fly. We do not have a standard list of services or fees as they are "tweaked" for each client. Believe me, I have tried to scale it down to even 30 different options and it is just not possible for what we do. That's why they have always edited last years letter in MS Word.

Comment: Could import data from spreadsheet into a normalized database structure with VBA. An alternative is to manipulate data after import with UNION query to arrange data into normalized structure and use that query as source for report. Or your idea of concatenating fields into a single string is also an option.

Comment: I have won a small battle and am approved to create a user entry form instead of the spreadsheet! The services and fees will still have so many possible combinations so I am thinking of creating a rich text field for both services and for fees. Is there a way to set the rich text field on a form (to add new records) to contain a default value that can be edited?